# Python: How to prevent python dictionary from putting quotes around my json?

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

I am using requests to create a post request on a contractor's API. I have a JSON variable `inputJSON` that undergoes formatting like so:

```
def dolayoutCalc(inputJSON):
    inputJSON = ast.literal_eval(inputJSON)
    inputJSON = json.dumps(inputJSON)
    url='http://xxyy.com/API'
    payload = {'Project': inputJSON, 'x':y, 'z':f}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

My issue arises when I define `payload={'Project':inputJSON, 'x':y, 'z':f}`
What ends up happening is Python places a pair of quotes around the inputJSON structure. The API I am hitting is not able to handle this. It needs Project value to be the exact same inputJSON value just without the quotes.

What can I do to prevent python from placing quotes around my `inputJSON` object? Or is there a way to use requests library to handle such POST request situation?

Comment: Do you really need `inputJSON = json.dumps(inputJSON)`?. Can you try without those?

Comment: Unfortunately the way we I am receiving the inputs from the frontend and the way it is stored in the SQLServer database cause some funky conversions of the original JSON. Turns out json.dumps is the final step I need to fix issues like having "False" instead of "false", etc.

Comment: What I mean is instead of using string as a value of `Project` use the json itself. If False and false are some issues, then you can use `json.loads(json.dumps(inputJSON))`.

Comment: When I pass in `json.laods(json.dumps(inputJSON))`, `json.loads()` seems to reverse the corrections that `json.dumps()` makes such as reverting "false" back to "False". As a result I get a 400 response and a message stating "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0):

inputJSON gets quotes around it because it's a string. When you call json.dumps() on something a string will come out, and then when it's converted to JSON it will get quotes around it. e.g.:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps('this is a string')
>>> '"this is a string"'
```

I'm with AKS in that should be able to remove this line:

```
inputJSON = json.dumps(inputJSON)
```

From your description inputJSON sounds like a Python literal (e.g. {'blah': True} instead of {"blah": true}. So you've used the ast module to convert it into a Python value, and then in the final json.dumps() it should be converted to JSON along with everything else.

Example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> import json
>>> input = "{'a_var': True}"   # A string that looks like a Python literal
>>> input = ast.literal_eval(input)   # Convert to a Python dict
>>> print input
>>> {'a_var': True}
>>> payload = {'Project': input}    # Add to payload as a dict
>>> print json.dumps(payload)
>>> {"Project": {"a_var": true}}    # In the payload as JSON without quotes
```